# Async File Deserialization

Tags: c#, wpf, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, async-await

I'm at my first Windows Store App, and I'm having some issue with Deserialization/loading my application Data.

I'm using JSon to serialize my class object to a string, then I'm saving it to the Application Local App folder.

When it is time to load the data, once upon a time the load fail at run time, and no data are loaded. and my classes are instantiated as a new classes.

But when I'm running my code step my step in debug mode. the Desirialization work OK and my classes are correctly loaded.

I'm thinking that the problem come from my async implementation. but I can't tell where.

Can some one help me?

**Save procedure:**

```
public virtual void Save()
{
     var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
     WriteTotextFileAsync("Cashier.Data.Config", data);
}

public static async void WriteTotextFileAsync(string fileName, string contents)
{
     var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
     var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
     await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, contents);
}
```

**Load procedure:**

```
private async void LoadConfig()
{
    string data;
    if (Config == null)
    {
        data = await ReadTextFileAsync("Cashier.Data.Config");//.ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (data != null && data.Length > 0)
            try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(data);
                Config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data.Config>(data);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(data);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var dlg = new MessageDialog("Desirialization erreur" + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
                dlg.ShowAsync();
                Config = new Config();
            }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Config = new Config();");
            Config = new Config();
        }
    }
}

public static async Task<string> ReadTextFileAsync(string path)
{
    var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    try
    {
        var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(path);
        var value = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
        return value;
    }
    catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fond what went wrong. When I was deserializing the string, I was casting it to the wrong object class type.

Answer (score 6):

You should avoid `async void`. Change your `LoadConfig` and `Save` methods into `async Task` methods and have your calling code `await` the task they return.

One problem with `async void` is that the calling code *cannot know* when it has completed. E.g., the code that calls `LoadConfig` does not know when the config is actually loaded. By making `LoadConfig` return a `Task`, then the calling code can `await` that `Task` and know that the config is loaded when that task completes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've async and Task as you suggest, but it did not change the behavior. Where exacty  is the best place to call a save setting procedure? In the "OnSuspending" event of App.xaml.cs?